# Can the Eclipse emulator be made less blurry when run on retina Mac hardware?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, android

I'm using Eclipse JUNO and ADT 21 on a MacBook Pro Retina 15" and the eclipse app itself looks very sharp (code blocks, images and texts). However, things are blurry in the Android Emulator.

[image]

What can I do to fix the blurriness of the emulator window?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse's text is high resolution because it is drawn by OS X's APIs. I assume the emulator is simulating the actual resolution of the device, so it might not be able to run at retina resolution.

You can increase the screen's resolution to make the problem less noticeable. Go to System Preferences > Display and select Scaled. This Apple support doc might help: [MacBook Pro: Frequently asked questions about using a Retina display](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5266?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

(The only way to get rid of blurriness completely is to [run your retina Mac at full resolution](http://www.mactrast.com/2012/06/running-retina-macbook-pro-full-2880x1800-resolution/).)

**Edit** - reword because I misread your question.

Comment: Note that by running at full resolution, the Android emulator will be much smaller (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience all Java 1.7 (eclipse run on Java) have blurry text on Mac retina .. according to some forum you have to downgrade to java 1.6 from Apple ..

1.8 should work with retina ..